# Key sequence cause song forward in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, media

I have Dell Inspiron 15 5000 series with windows 10. Every time i type the sequence "hui" on the keyboard , windows is forwarding a song , it happens both in spotify desktop and windows media player. i never changed any hot keys or installed any keyboard add on . couldnt find any information about it . the issue is that in my language , the key sequence hui is very common..

Comment: Does this only happen with this exact sequence or also with any of the letters on its own (e.g. only pressing i) or in combination (e.g. ui)

Comment: only hui .tried all combination ..